# use redux and redux toolkit together

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a project that uses the old redux store, reducers and actions.And, recently, we could like to introduce redux toolkit with this. So, we would like to keep our existing redux implementations and take into use the new redux toolkit with the new implementations.

So, to achieve that I am trying to use two different store, once from the existing redux store and another from the redux toolkit store. But, this seems doesn't work and in my component, I am not able to access the state from the redux toolkit store, Which is basically from storeA.

Here is the Sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-redux-boilerplate-forked-rgmmzf?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10006356jhvpyjcgu%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10002356jfrc3hjis%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10003356jpgnqccns%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10005356jsom54h49%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls38fxn10002356jfrc3hjis%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10001356jfedf4nlc%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10002356jfrc3hjis%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10001356jfedf4nlc%2522%257D%252C%2522cls38fxn10005356jsom54h49%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10004356jzawel3qb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10005356jsom54h49%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10004356jzawel3qb%2522%257D%252C%2522cls38fxn10003356jpgnqccns%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls38fxn10003356jpgnqccns%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) that I am trying.

I have two store in `index.js`

```
<Provider store={storeA}>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
</Provider>
```

storeA includes the `todoSlice` which is basically created with redux toolkit implementation.

And in my component, in App.js, I am trying to access the state:

```
 const taskState = useSelector((state) => state);
 console.log(taskState);
```

but taskState, doesn't retunr anything or it is undefined when trying to see in the console.

Does anybody know what woulb be th best approach to acheive this, or is this even possible? I have seen some thread that we can use two different store. Any helps would be highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While there *is* an old "use case" and workaround for using [Multiple Stores](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#multiple-stores) it is ***not recommended at all*** and just swapping over to the Redux-Toolkit (RTK) store and integrating your existing reducers probably took less time than it took me to search through Redux for the documentation.

**/src/reducers/index.js**

Import all the reducers, including your newer RTK slice reducers.

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import loginReducer from "./loginReducer";
import todoReducer from "../todoSlice"; // <-- new import

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  login: loginReducer,
  todo: todoReducer, // <-- combine
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**/src/storeA.js**

Use just the exported root reducer.

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const storeA = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default storeA;
```

***/src/App.jsx***

Import and use ***just*** the new RTK store.

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
import storeA from "./redux/storeA";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={storeA}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also noticed that we can still use the existing createStore method and use import the new slice reducers.

Comment: @ninja Sure, that also works, but I thought you were trying to move forward and use the newer RTK code. The legacy `createStore` is actually marked as deprecated in recent versions if I'm not mistaken. Either will work though.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that in my actual codebase there are some legacy stuff from the old reducers and using the configureStore there breaks lot's of stuff there.

Comment: I actually tried your approach as well. Noticed that the dispatch can't find the appropriate functions from the slice reducer. Do you have any idea what I am missing there still: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-redux-boilerplate-forked-rgmmzf

Comment: @ninja Interesting. When I integrated RTK into an existing "legacy" Redux store app it went way smoother than I had ever expected, about a 10-15 minute integration on  a production app. Sure in this using the older store is fine, though I'd recommend you update those older reducers sooner rather than later.

Comment: @ninja Taking a look now at your sandbox.

Comment: Okay, fixed that dispatch problem. actually forgot to import the increment function there before dispatching it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256749/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ninja).